# Internal linking not working in mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm finishing up my portfolio project for FreeCodeCamp, its a simple one page site. My problem is that internal linking is not working in mobile, I have tried a few different potential fixes but none of them work, and the same problem persists. The current code works fine on desktop, and while in mobile view in the inspector. When I try clicking the link to scroll to the contact section in mobile the screen just flickers white for a moment, and nothing happens. This is the case even if I remove the jQuery animating the scroll. What would be causing this not to work?

http://codepen.io/Adev/pen/VjqERp

currently linking this way:

```
<li><a href="#contactSec" id="contactScroll">Contact</a></li>

to

<a name="contactSec"></a>
```

Also tried:

```
<li><a href="#contact" id="contactScroll">Contact</a></li>

to

<div class="container" id="contact">
```

While these all work in the pen, they do not work in mobile. At this point I'm not sure what else to try, suggestions will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I can see that you are overriding the default scrolling behaviour using jQuery. Try animating the scrollTop property of both body and html elements, instead of just body only, i.e. `$('html body').stop().animate({...})`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What you've suggested was the original code, and that did not work either.